# develop ios 8 keyboard and widgets using flash air

Tags: flash, air, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

IOS 8 will have third-party keyboard and widgets as apple said

and you know that it's possible to develop IOS apps using flash air

so , is that possible to develop keyboard and widgets for apple using flash air ?

I know that the answer is probably no , but , is there a way to turn around that ?

and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given Adobe's history with supporting native APIs, the answer is almost certainly no. We're still waiting for a way to create native alerts and dialogs from within AIR. There is no way they would give us the ability to create keyboards and widgets before something as simple as that.

It would be possible to do via an ANE, but it would be pointless since it would have to be done entirely in Objective-C or Swift anyway.

It's also worth noting that Android has supported third-party keyboards and widgets since the beginning. Adobe has never once made a move toward supporting the creation of these or given any indication that they intended to. Such things are not within the primary scope of their AIR project and never have been.

Answer (score 0):

For now - no, it's available only for native code. And as far as I see, AIR won't be developed a lot further, so they won't add any support even if Apple open the door.. Sorry to say that.